# RTL text in username messes up formatting of usercard

Tags: bug, formatting

I noticed something interesting today when I looked at the usercard of a [high-rep user](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/4730/seyyed-ali-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C):

[image: bad format usercard]

I saw that, and was immediately confused because I saw what appeared to be a reputation of 46 and knew that was incorrect.  When I saw that he also had 3k gold badges and [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) text in his username, I immediately knew what had happened. Looks like RTL text in a username messes up the formatting of the usercard.

Related, but not exactly the same: [Please add Right To Left text support in Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5303/189898)

Comment: Oh, yeah. That looks interesting! searched to some extent, it seems i've got 3332 gold medal !  I appreciate your really precise paying attention to this point.

Comment: Note: I edited my name in order to help the site for this trouble. But, on the whole, this problem ought to be deemed to remove its difficulty.

Comment: Pretty sure, that's a known bug. And has its meta some-somewhere. Too lazy to dig.